# Proper Raycast with ARCORE

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, arcore

I try to add some simple raycasting effect in my app. Work perfectly in Editor but as soon as I try to use it with ARCORE I'm unnable to make a proper raycast...

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.Rendering;
using GoogleARCore;


public class RaycastObject : MonoBehaviour
{
    public enum HoverState { HOVER, NONE };
    public HoverState hover_state = HoverState.NONE;

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () {

    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        RaycastHit hit;
        Ray ray = Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay(Input.mousePosition);

        if (Physics.Raycast(ray, out hit)) //If collision
        {
            if (hover_state == HoverState.NONE && hit.transform.tag == "TestCollider") //if gamertag
            {
                Destroy(hit.transform.gameObject);
                hover_state = HoverState.HOVER;
            }
            else if(hover_state == HoverState.HOVER && hit.transform.tag != "TestCollider")
            {
                hover_state = HoverState.NONE;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            if (hover_state == HoverState.HOVER) //if gamertag
            {
                hover_state = HoverState.NONE;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I put this code on my First Person Camera in ARCORe Device object. Does I have to use TrackableHit instead of RaycastHit ? Does someone have a proper example or can help me to correct my code ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally work, I had to pass the ARController in public and drag & drop it in the Inspector !

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using GoogleARCore.HelloAR;

public class RaycastCatchObject : MonoBehaviour
{
    private GameObject childObject;
    public ExampleARController helloAr;
    public enum HoverState { HOVER, NONE };
    public HoverState hover_state = HoverState.NONE;

    private void Start()
    {
        helloAr._ShowAndroidToastMessage("Awake");
    }

    //Update is called once per frame
    public void FixedUpdate()
    {
        Vector3 fwd = transform.TransformDirection(Vector3.forward);

        RaycastHit hit;

        if (Physics.Raycast(transform.position, fwd, out hit)) //if hit a 3D Object
        {
            if (hover_state == HoverState.NONE && hit.transform.tag == "gameObjectCollider") //if object hit get a tag gameObjectCollider
            {
                helloAr._ShowAndroidToastMessage("In");
                hover_state = HoverState.HOVER;
            }
            else if (hover_state == HoverState.HOVER && hit.transform.tag != "gameObjectCollider")
            {
                helloAr._ShowAndroidToastMessage("Out");
                hover_state = HoverState.NONE;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            if (hover_state == HoverState.HOVER)
            {
                helloAr._ShowAndroidToastMessage("Out");
                hover_state = HoverState.NONE;
            }
        }
    }
}
```